# How to prevent hexadecimal value being converted to scientific notation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, char, hex

When saving certain hexadecimal values to our database, they are being converted to what I think is scientific (E) notation. e.g. `558E74` becomes `5.6e76`.

I can understand that the number `558E74` is also represented as `5.6e76`, but the value is not intended to be a number, so the conversion is not what we're after!

We're currently using:

- MySQL 5.7
- Column type is `char` with a max length of 6

How can we prevent the values from being converted? Is there something we can change about the way they are saved? Or should we be using a different column type?

I feel like I might be missing something fairly obvious as this seems like quite a basic question (apologies if so!), but having searched around I was struggling to find any answers.

Answer (score 1):

If its a character destination, quote it, otherwise [hexadecimal literal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/hexadecimal-literals.html) like `0x558E74`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! It would be really helpful if you could expand on your answer a little bit - for example, is it just a case of increasing our `char` column's length to 8 and adding the `0x` to the start of the string and stripping it back out again when retrieving the data? Or do we need to change the column type to binary? Or something else altogether? Thanks! :)

Comment: How are you using a HEX number in the column? Is it a pure identifier or is ordering required? Inserting it quoted `INSERT INTO .. VALUES ('558E74')` would be the best way for a char(6). Binary is an option because its not a character set. If you changed the column to an integer then use the hex notation for inserting (and don't quote it).

Comment: Ah ok, thanks! Purely to store and retrieve a user-picked hex so they can apply a custom theme to one area of or application. No ordering required or anything like that - literally just a case of them setting the colour in the settings, then we pull it and inline the colour when generating the relevant section's markup. We'll have a go! I'm on a/l now for a week so apologies if I don't reply for a few days. :)